# How to solve patch update/revert errors? SUPEE-6285 and 1.9.2.0

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, ce-1.9.2.0, supee-6285

While reverting the SUPEE-6285 patch (in order to install SUPEE-6285-V2), I get errors like

> patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
>   Hunk #1 FAILED at 33.
>   1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml.rej

I've had these before with different patches, but usually replacing these files with a file solves the problem. With this patch however, replacing with files from both magento 1.9.2 pre and post the SUPEE-6285 V2 patch doesn't work.

I'm running 1.9.2. Is anyone else facing this problem? And what is best practice for patching? I would guess you should do something with the .rej file, they aren't created.

Comment: You are upgraded to 1.9.2.0, correct? It was supposed to be completely patched to include patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6285 and needs no further interference.

Comment: Well, it looks like I read the patch notes a little too fast. Thanks for clearing things up for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** this answer applies to Magento 1.9.1.1 and earlier, Magento 1.9.2.0 does not need any of the current patches (up to SUPEE-6285), which is also the reason for your error messages.

---

You need to apply SUPEE-5994 first, because it patched the same file and it is the first patch that is not already contained in Magento 1.9.1.1

Comment: Applying an unneeded patch on 1.9.2.0

Comment: My fault, didn't read the version correctly. Of course 1.9.2 does not need any of the current patches

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the patch notes completely. I'll accept your answer because it might help others.

Answer (score 2):

`app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml`

The SUPEE-6285 V2 Patch adds the `quoteEscape()` function to take care of the XSS issue.

If you are running 1.9.2.0, it is already patched with SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994 and SUPEE-6285. The Continue Shopping button is escaped to prevent XSS as follows (as extracted from Magento 1.9.2.0 archive file):

```
<?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Continue Shopping')) ?>" class="button2 btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code in 1.9.1.1 allows for XSS and is as follows (as extracted from Magento 1.9.1.1 archive file):

```
<?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button2 btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
<?php endif; ?>
```

What the SUPEE-6285 v2 patch does to `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml` in 1.9.x.x prior to 1.9.2.0 which already includes the fix:

```
    <?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
-       <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button2 btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
+       <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Continue Shopping')) ?>" class="button2 btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Diff of SUPEE-6285 V1 vs. V2 shows the only change was the RWD template:

```
160c160
< SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v1 | 7226d88b1eeb07a5fbc4e62be189a5219457cc14 | Mon Jun 22 16:32:26 2015 +0300 | 202596e441..7226d88b1e
---
> SUPEE-6285 | CE_1.9.1.1 | v2 | 7226d88b1eeb07a5fbc4e62be189a5219457cc14 | Mon Jun 22 16:32:26 2015 +0300 | 202596e441..7226d88b1e
1065a1065,1077
> diff --git app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> index 7bceece..88753c3 100644
> --- app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> +++ app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml
> @@ -115,7 +115,7 @@
>                          <span class="or">-<?php echo $this->__('or'); ?>-</span>
>  
>                          <?php if($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()): ?>
> -                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?>" class="button2 btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getContinueShoppingUrl() ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
> +                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->quoteEscape($this->__('Continue Shopping')) ?>" class="button2 btn-continue" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->getContinueShoppingUrl()) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Continue Shopping') ?></span></span></button>
>                          <?php endif; ?>
>                          <!--[if lt IE 8]>
>                          <input type="hidden" id="update_cart_action_container" />
```

Comment: Great explanation about the patch. Thanks. (Unfortunately I just didn't read, see also the comment below my question)